# How can I get the serial number of my cameras in C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, camera

I would like to get the serial number of my cameras in C++ (probably using OpenCV library). In fact, I should synchronize two cameras. To do so, I need a way to get the serial number of cameras to see if it is the right one or the left one.
I would be most grateful if someone can give me some advice about that.

Comment: The name of the camera depends on the OS, but the Serial Number of Camera is something Fixed and it is a factory set property. So, it is not dependent on the OS.

Comment: afaik, opencv doesnt support getting a lot of camera info. There a getParameter function (and a setParameter), which you can use to get the fps etc. if the driver supports it. And this getParameter function has gotten some new parameters within th last years, so maybe have a look at the newest opencv version and the supported parameters. Otherwise you'll have to use a different camera library, like videoInput library (windows) or video4linux. Or, if you use a professional camera, they typically provide an SDK and you should use it.

Comment: You camera webcam or camera has own sdk?